# 知らせる・知らされる conjugation

Tags: grammar, verbs, conjugations, causation

知らされる means "to be informed".

知らせる means "to inform"

Why is 知らせされる not used? I almost always hear/see 知らされる。Is it a different verb entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also a verb 知らす "to inform/notify" and 知らされる is the passive of this verb.

As explained in @l'électeur's answer to the question [Causative せる/させる vs. す/さす](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43474/1628), 知らす is an older form (文語体) of 知らせる (口語体) with the same meaning. (Most if not all causative forms ～せる can be thought of having derived from an older ～す verb.)

---

You also ask about *知らせ**され**る, which is not a correct form. The causative of 知らせる is 知らせ**させ**る. The passive is 知らせ**られ**る.

#### Causative 知らせさせる

知らせる (and 知らす) are already the causative form of 知る, even if they are used more idiomatically as "to inform", rather than the literal "to make [someone] know".

In any case, the causative of 知らせる, which would be 知らせさせる, could in principle be used, e.g.

> 知らせさせてください
> Please allow me to inform [someone else]

However, such cases are probably quite rare.

#### Passive 知らせられる vs 知らされる

As you seem to have noticed, 知らせられる and 知らされる are passives of two different but related verbs that mean the same thing.

I think 知らされる can be thought of as the *de facto* passive of 知らせる. 知らせられる appears not to be used. (At least not as a passive; of course, the potential is of the same form.)

Something similar seems to happen with other verbs. For example, やる has a causative やらせる and *de facto* passive やらされる. The passive やらせられる is hardly ever used.

Comment: i was using the abbreviated passive-causative in 知らせされる similar to 食べされる＝食べさせられる。

edit: apparently that isn't a thing and only applies to some verbs

Comment: @frei I'm not sure there is an abbreviated passive-causative. I only know of an abbreviated potential (～られる → ～れる, also works for potential-causative) and of the above-mentioned abbreviation by replacing ～せる by ～す for various conjugations. Note that even though passive and potential look the same on "vowel stem" verbs, both ending in ～られる, you can only use ～られる → ～れる for the potential *not* for the passive.

Comment: yeah it looks like for some verbs there isn't an abbreviated passive-causative, which was actually the source of most of my confusion surrounding how to conjugate it